# Replacing strings in xml file using batch script

Tags: web-services, powershell, batch-file, jboss

I'm new to batch script. I want to replace a strings in a particular file.
In below script I'm getting error.

```
@echo off
$standalone = Get-Content 'C:\wildfly\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml'

$standalone -replace '<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>','<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}</wsdl-host>' | 
Set-Content 'C:\wildfly\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml'
```

Comment: Line 1 is batch, rest is PowerShell.

Comment: I want to write in batch script only

Comment: You don't want to edit XML files in batch. Trust me.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Okay But I need to change some data in ds.xml files(present in configuration folder of wildfly). Is it possible to change with batch script.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to edit XML is to process it as an XML document, not as a string. That's because the XML file is not guaranteed to maintain specific formatting. Any edits should be context-aware and string replace isn't. Consider the three eqvivalent XML fragments:

```
<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>

<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host >

<wsdl-host >${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host >
```

Note that whitespacing in element names is different and [it's legal](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) to add some. What's more, in practice, a lot of implementations simply discard line breaks in element values, so the two following are likely to provide same results to a config parser:

```
<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>

<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}
</wsdl-host>
```

It really doesn't make much sense to process XML as string, does it?

Fortunately, Powershell has built-in support for XML files. A simple approach is like so,

```
# Mock XML config
[xml]$x = @'
<root>
<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
</root>
'@

# Let's change the wsdl-host element's contents
$x.root.'wsdl-host' = '${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}'

# Save the modified document to console to see the change
$x.save([console]::out)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<root>
  <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}</wsdl-host>
</root>
```

If you can't use Powershell and are stuck with batch scripts, you really need to use a 3rd party XML manipulation program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I want to change the in wildfly that too in filesare in .xml format only.where can i give the path of the file in the script